# Ethernet problem, LAN cable appears unplugged

Tags: networking, ethernet

LAN cable is shown as unplugged, but the LAN cable is connected and the  port is fine.

[image]

Comment: Does it change after `ip link set enp1s0 up`? And please don't post text as pictures. Use formatting instead and post text as text.